# Firefox 52 Insecure Connection Fix

Tags: security, firefox, browser, connection

Last night my Firefox Browser updated, but it asked me a question about allowing the update before proceeding, which I thought was odd, but continued, as it's Firefox. So now I'm on version 52 and I keep seeing a connection error:

[image]

I need to log into my PHPMyAdmin on Localhost but see this message first. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security feature in new versions of Firefox.

There is actually no error, this just warns you that the login information will be sent over a non-encrypted channel.

You can ignore this warning and logon nevertheless. This is okay, when working with logins on your own computer or when working with logins in your own private local network.

When the login form is on a server in the internet or some other public or workplace network, make sure to enable and use https for the site so that login information is not sent without encryption.

[Information by Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Protect-your-privacy/Insecure-password-warning-in-Firefox/ta-p/27861)

---

You can disable this feature in Firefox the following way (NOT advised!):

1. Enter `about:config` into the address field.
2. Conform the warning that you want to change settings
3. Enter `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` into the Search field
4. Double click the shown entry `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` to set it to `false`.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually getting it on a few of my online logins too, although haven't actually logged in due to seeing the warning. The link you gave givs an invalid page, but am I right in assuming that I'd need to change `http://` to `https://`

Comment: Cheers NineBerry. I've tried adding https to one of my online log-ins, but it keeps reverting me back to one without a http:// prefix, and I'm still shown the connection error. Does this mean the site doesn't have a secure login method?

Comment: @SteveGee yes, sadly some sites don't implement https yet.

Comment: What would you advise on this sort of thing? I mean the site is an ad network ( Revenue Hits ), so it does potentially hold a lot of financial details for many of it's customers. I've been able to log in until recently too!

Comment: @SteveGee You can still login. The new Firefox feature is just a warning that you can ignore. When the site does not offer https, you have sent login information unencrypted in the past, you just didn't notice because there was no warning.

Comment: Oh so this **is** purely due to the Firefox 52 update? I did wonder. Thanks again.

Comment: One other question though... Is there any way to stop it showing this message **every** time I log in?

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry. As I don't want to dissable the security feature completely I probably won't use this method, but it is useful to know. What I actually meant was, is there a way to stop it showing on **specific websites**, like my server localhost, or RH?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for your connection is not secure or insecure connection

it is very easy to fix this problem
In CONTROL PANEL choose WINDOWS FIREWALL and click on ALLOW AN APP OR FEATURE THROUGH WINDOWS FIREWALL 
click on CHANGE SETTINGS 
 now find the browser which you used i.e. firefox google chrome and tick both side PUBLIC or PRIVATE then OK

now your problem is gone